# How do I connect mongodb to an existing set of database files

Tags: macos, mongodb

I downloaded a mongoDB database, meaning I got a set of XXX.0 [xxx.1, ...] and XXX.ns files. I installed mongoDB (on Mac OS X using Homebrew) and ran mongod with the dbpath parameter pointing to a directory with these files in it. However, when I use the mongo shell and ask to see available databases or collections, I get nothing but the 'local' database and no collections. What am I doing wrong? how can I get mongoDB to 'see' the database in the directory?
Thanks,
Yariv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the database files naming that you have downloaded, the files were generated using [MongoDB MMAPv1 storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/mmapv1/). As if it were generated with [MongoDB WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/wiredtiger/), you would have `collection.*.wt` files.

Now, if you have just installed through homebrew the latest stable version of MongoDB which is currently v3.2. This would have come with the [new default storage engine of WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#wiredtiger-as-default).

If you also have the `local.<n>` and `local.ns` files in the directory, MongoDB would give you an error stating incompatibility of storage files like below:

```
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28662 Cannot start server. Detected data files in /data/target created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, but the specified storage engine was 'mmapv1'., terminating
```

Without these files `mongod` will run with WiredTiger storage engine and would ignore the existing(copied) MMAPv1 files.

If this is your case, you can run `mongod` with the [--storageEngine](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#storage-options) option to specify MMAPv1. This would set `mongod` to run with MMAPv1 storage engine. Example:

```
mongod --dbpath <your db files dir> --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

Also for the record, checkout [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to export/import the database contents in binary format instead of copying the database files.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that several WiredTiger files were automatically created when I ran mongod with the default storage engine (WiredTiger). So when running with the --storageEngine=mmapv1 switch I got an error. But after deleting all files except the .<n> and .ns ones, and running with the switch, it works great.